# Is my interpretation correct?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, quantum-computing

I am trying to implement the algorithm described in the paper [A quantum-inspired classical algorithm for
recommendation systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.04271.pdf).

This is the algorithm:

[image]

These are the necessary definitions for mathematical notations used in the algorithm to understand the algorithm.

> The distribution is defined as, for a nonzero vector $x \in R^n$, we
>   denote by  $\mathrm{D}_x$ the distribution over [1, ..., n] whose
>   probability density function is $$\mathrm{D}_x(i) =\frac{x^{2}_{i}}{\lVert{x}\rVert ^2} $$.
>
> If a matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$, and let $A_i$  refer to the $i$th
>   row of $A$. Let $\tilde{A} \in R^m$ be a vector whose $i$th entry is
>   $\lVert A_i \rVert$.
>
> $[p] denotes [1, 2, ... p]$
>
> $s \sim _u [p]$ denotes pulling an $s$ uniformly at random.

I am having a problem understanding the `Let the resulting p x p submatrix ...` step of the algorithm. According to the algorithm the rows of the submatrix are sampled from a distribution $\mathrm{D}_{\tilde{A}}$ and the columns of the submatrix are sampled from a distribution $\mathcal{F}$.

1. I can't understand how can we form a submatrix with both rows and
   colums given ? I think we just need either rows or columns. Can someone clarify
   this to me, please ?
2. And I also don't understand the definition of $\mathcal{F}$.
   According to definition of $\mathcal{D}_x$, $x$ has to be a vector
   then how can we choose a column from $D_ \tilde{A_{i_s}}$.

Comment: I doubt this algorithm is useful in practice. For example, the constant $10^7$ in the definition of $p$ is rather large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a matrix $A$, you can form another matrix by taking only some of the rows and columns of $A$, possibly repeated. For example, suppose that $A$ is the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we take only rows 1,2 and columns 1,3, then we get the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
4 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For your second question, $\mathcal{D}_x$ is a distribution on column *indices*. You don't choose a column directly – you only choose an index. This corresponds to 1,3 in the example above.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my idea of forming a submatrix from a larger matrix is selecting rows and columns at random without replacement and in increasing order. So what does $sample$ $ rows$ $ i_1, ..., i_p$ $from $ $\mathcal{D}_{\tilde{A}}$ mean ? Are we sampling indices at random or sampling from $\mathcal{D}_{\tilde{A}}$ distribution.

Comment: It means to sample indices of rows, according to the distribution $\mathcal{D}_{\tilde{A}}$. Rows can repeat, and they don't need to be in increasing order.

Comment: How can we sample a column from $\mathcal{D}_{\tilde{A}}$. The contents of $\tilde{A_{i_s}}$ is l2 norms of row vectors. Can you clarify to me `Let F denote the distribution given....` step ?

Comment: You use the definition of $\mathcal{D}_x$, which applies for any vector $x$, for example $x=\tilde{A}$, whose entries are the norms of the rows of $A$.

Comment: How is the distribution $\mathcal{F}$ formed  ?

Comment: There's probably a typo there – you should sample from $\mathcal{D}_{A_{i_s}}$ (without the tilde). To be sure, follow the proof and see what it uses.

Comment: After going through the proofs again, I think your interpretation is correct because it doesn't make sense to sample from $\mathcal{D_{\tilde{A_{i_s}}}}$